# Authenticating a file stream from android to wcf

Tags: android, wcf, post, android-asynctask, wcf-security

I have an app that makes request to a wcf service. Usually I authenticate all of the requests using a hash value that is sent in the body of the request and then authenticated on the server. All most all of the request are sent via json and it is easy for me to add the hash value to the body of the request. The issue I am facing is that when I send a file stream I cannot add the hash to the body of the request so I am wondering how I can authenticate that the request came from my app and not from some where else. All suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered a header with the hash in it? If it does not have it, or is incorrect, reject it.
Edit: wording.

Comment: I have not, but I don't know how to implement that, that sounds like what I'm looking. Suggestions or links to examples?

Comment: thanks thats what I wanted. Is that secure, is there any way for someone to read the headers of the request?

Comment: [This](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html) is what I was getting at. Otherwise, you can check also [this](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/06/restful-services-authenticating-clients.html) link, since it was a long time ago when I read those.

Second comment: I am not so good in that department, I guess open another question about that. AFAIK it is good enough, yet I might be very wrong.

Comment: also feel free to create an answer if you want the reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an authorization item in the header is a possible solution. So, if anyone is interested, read [this](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html) and [this](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/06/restful-services-authenticating-clients.html).